# Copying list item between sites with REST/JSON HTTP Call from Workflow: Why wont these columns copy?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api, http-400-bad-request

This is a re-post with more information hoping for a better response.

I have 2 lists in a SharePoint site with the following columns:

List 1

- project ID = Single line of text
- event type = Choice
- event desc = Single line of text
- owning dept = Choice
- external = Multiple lines of text
- internal = People and Groups
- minutes = Multiple lines of text
- outcome = Multiple lines of text

List 2

- project status = Choice
- phase = Choice
- owner = People and Groups
- date modified = DateModified

on item creation I want a SharePoint 2013 Workflow to copy the content of these columns to an identical list another site. I have successfully built the HTTP call and the workflow currently creates a new item in the target list with the following columns copied correctly:

- project ID
- event desc
- minutes
- outcome
- phase

The other seven columns all return BadRequest when I attempt to add them to the parameters variable. here are some screenshots of my current configuration.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Based on this setup, can anyone tell or point me to a resource on how the remaining seven fields should e configured?

Comment: What is the error, is there any more info past bad request? Also, have you tried to do the remaining seven columns, 1 column at a time?

Comment: No, there's no more info than bad request. After much trial and error I've managed to get the choice fields working. the people fields refuse to cooperate

Comment: Please make sure to post what you did to get the fields working so that there is a trail :). Glad you got the choice field working. Perhaps the people field has to do with using the value of Email Address, Display Name or possibly username/account name. I have had success using the account name before.